# Set and get Environment Variable from script Bitrise

Tags: bitrise

I want to set environment variable from script in Bitrise.
for example I am setting build version based on date like 03.16 and build number start from 1. once date change from ex 17th march than build version will change to 03.17 and build number start from 1 again.
I have script to set build version and build number. I can generate build version from shell command but I have to store build number. every build trigger in same date build number will increase by one

for example
first build on 16th march version would be 03.16(1)
second build on 16th march version would be 03.16(2)
.
.
first build on 17th march version would be 03.17(1)
second build on 17th march version would be 03.17(2)

Comment: It's technically doable, though not a super simple thing to do. Essentially for this you need some kind of key-value storage most likely. An alternative, which would be super simple to implement could be to just use the `$BITRISE_BUILD_NUMBER` ( https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/references/available-environment-variables.html#available-environment-variables ) env var. You can still prefix it with the date, but instead of trying to reset it to 1 every day, you'd just use the build number (e.g. `03.16(232)`). The advantage of this is that you can also identify which build created it.

Comment: @ViktorBenei I can not use $BITRISE_BUILD_NUMBER because I have to reset build number to 1 every day. it is stander in our organisation I can not change it.

Comment: In that case, a solution could be to use a Script in your build which pings the Bitrise API, fetching the builds for the day, and you'd just use that as the build number https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/api.html#api